# Bootstrap 4 collapse not working when used in a flex

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble with Bootstrap 4 collapse. it works perfectly fine if i don't use "d-flex" class in my form tag.

However if i use "d-flex", the form is shown by default. when the #reservas_button is clicked, the form is toggled to hidden then back to shown.

```
    <!--reservas-->
<div id="reservas" class="container d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row align-items-center align-items-sm-start">
  <h2 id="reservas_button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#reservas_form">RESERVAS</h2>
  <form id="reservas_form" class="collapse d-flex flex-wrap">

    ...

</div>
<!--/reservas-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the div with display flex into a wrapper and collapse the wrapper (another div), works well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use d-flex in form tag. it is likely overwriting collapse. Your snippet works if you omit d-flex.

Comment: And that's the problem is which I am trying to find a solution. I prefer using the built in functions from bootstrap. If it is not possible then I may try to use custom Jquery instead. Any alternative solution?

Comment: Why do you need a d-flex again in form? It is going to inherit that already from container. You can continue to have a d-flex in container div. I don't see any change if you remove it just from form

Comment: thanks for the response. I was away for some times. I will check this one out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
style="display:flex;"
```

instead of `d-flex` in you class.